# Какую роль в этом скрипте играет "* *"?

Tags: perl

имеется следующий скрипт:

```
echo 'eval{print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}' | perl
```

И еще несколько вариантов:

```
echo '@${print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}' | perl

echo '$${print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}' | perl

echo 'do{print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}' | perl

echo '$#{print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}' | perl
```

Скажите пожалуйста, какую роль в данном случае играет "* *"? 
(Так же работает, если * * сменить на & &.)

Comment: Таки это было «И»?

Comment: Не знаю, просто ваш ответ единственный - поэтому я выбрал его.

Comment: Благодарю, однако. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо это блоки «И», ведь после каждого блока с `{ }` вы не указываете новый `eval` А просто как бы пишете

```
eval{} и {} и {}
```

Comment: Еще корректно работает в таком случае:     echo '$${print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}' | perl

Comment: И так тоже: echo '@${print "Just ";} * * {print "Another ";} * * {print "Perl ";} * * {print "Hacker\n";}' | perl

Comment: Ну в этих случаях оно наверное принимает эти символы за функцию Eval, хотя вроде как `@` это игнорирования ошибок.

Comment: eval{}, как мне кажется не при делах вообще.